# For mysql return values, how can I modify to make it show in Mega, kilo and G

Tags: mysql

The following is an example of a mysql return column.
select bandwidth from aTable

445355099

986654

7521

....

How can I modify to show in Mega, kilo and G?

424M

963k

7.3k

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  We are not a code generation service.  Please show what you've tried and/or researched thus far so we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Take a returned result, and:

- If it's greater than 1073741824 (1024 cubed), divide it by this number 1073741824 and round the result, then append `G`;
- If it's greater than 1048576 (1024 squared), divide by 1048576, round the result and append `M`;
- If it's greater then 1024, divide it by 1024, round the result and append `k`;
- Otherwise return as is, probably appending `bytes`.